# What will paymentIntents return if confirmation fails due to any reason?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

```
const payment_intent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
          customer: customer_id,
          payment_method: pm_id,
          amount: 1000,
          currency: "usd",
          confirm: true,
          off_session: true,
          //-------------------------------------
        });
```

The question is:

1. From the returned object, `payment_intent`, how can I check if the payment confirmation was successfully charged?
2. Will it throw an error if it fails or will it return some flag to indicated failure?

Answer (score 1):

[`stripe.paymentIntents.create`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create) returns a [PaymentIntent object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object), which contains the [last_payment_error](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-last_payment_error) property, which contains *"The payment error encountered in the previous PaymentIntent confirmation."* So, if it fails you can find the reason for it in that property.

To know, if it succeeded, you can check the [status](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-status) property of the PaymentIntent object. Which returns `succeeded`, if it did. Or shows the current status, if it didn't succeed, yet.

EDIT

It would throw an error, if an API call is prevented from continuing, which could have many reasons, including a card error. A list of possible errors can be seen [here](https://stripe.com/docs/error-handling?lang=node#error-types).

Comment: What about throwing an error? Under what scenario will that happen?

Comment: I edited my answer to include some info about errors.